# Mac OSX objective-c NSString memory leaking with ARC

Tags: objective-c, macos, memory-leaks, nsstring, automatic-ref-counting

Today I've tested around a with `NSStrings`. Sadly I have a serious memory leak when I run this code (xcode instruments are showing me that):

```
- (IBAction)start:(id)sender {
    while (true)  // Yes I know that this is an infinity loop
    {
        NSString *test = [[NSString alloc] init];
        test = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"llalalallalalallalalalalallalalllallalalallalal"];
        test = nil; 
        // Why does this leak memory ? I think ARC is releasing it automatically ?
    }
}
```

Here's a screenshot of the instruments:

[image]

Could me please help me to understand **why is this code leaking** (ARC is on)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The memory is just in the autorelease pool, the memory is reclaimed when the pool is drained. Usually this is when the run loop cycles but in a tight loop like this the run loop never get a chance so the pool needs to be explicitly drained.

In a situation like this just inside toe loop add an autorelease pool:

```
@autoreleasepool {
    code
}
```

In this case:

```
while (true)  // Yes I know that this is an infinity loop
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSString *test = [[NSString alloc]init];
        test = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"llalalallalalallalalalalallalalllallalalallalal"];
        test = nil; 
    }
}
```

BTW `stringWithFormat` with no format codes does nothing more than just create the string the same as if it were defined literally:

```
test = @"llalalallalalallalalalalallalalllallalalallalal";
```